# How to email multiple address with MSbuild

Tags: msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

I have a target in my build script that will send an email with an attachment detailing svn changes for a module.

This works if I hard code a single email address however I now want to email multiple developers and the script is failing. Below is the code

```
 <Target Name="MailInformationUpdate" DependsOnTargets="ZipArtifact" Condition="!Exists('BUILD_IS_PERSONAL')">

    <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(BuildDir)\$(recipientListFileName)">
      <Output PropertyName="Recipients"  TaskParameter="Lines"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <Mail SmtpServer="$(smptServer)"
           To="@(Recipients)"
           From="$(senderEmail)"
           Body="Attached is a list of the changes made since the last release. "
       Subject="This module has been updated. You may wish to update." Attachments="$(BuildDir)\Builds\$(svnChangeFileName)"   
          />    
  </Target>
```

If I change the To line to read $(Recipients) the first person on the list will get the email, subsequent addresses do not recieve the email.

I then changed the To line to what you see below @(Recipients),  as I thougt it might then loop round each recipient. No such luck!!! I get the error message

```
Emailing "{0}".
    <path> error : A recipient must be specified.
```

The file that I read in is simply a text file in the format (emailAddress1),(emailAddress2), etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The task **ReadLinesFromFile** reads a list of items from a text file. But the file must have one item on each line.

With your text file in the format (emailAdress1),emailAddress2)... you will only have one item containing *(emailAdress1),emailAddress2)...*.
Your email.txt should be like this:

```
emailAdress1
emailAdress2
...
```

You get items from ReadLinesFromFile task and not properties, so modify your task like that:

```
<Target Name="MailInformationUpdate" DependsOnTargets="ZipArtifact" Condition="!Exists('BUILD_IS_PERSONAL')">

  <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(BuildDir)\$(recipientListFileName)">
    <Output ItemName="Recipients"  TaskParameter="Lines"/>
  </ReadLinesFromFile>
  <Mail SmtpServer="$(smptServer)"
       To="@(Recipients)"
       From="$(senderEmail)"
       Body="Attached is a list of the changes made since the last release. "
       Subject="This module has been updated. You may wish to update."
       Attachments="$(BuildDir)\Builds\$(svnChangeFileName)"   
      />    
</Target>
```

(There is a bug in the log of the mail target, even with multiple recipients only the first one will be shown in the log.)